# Chrome web request blocking not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use the webrequest api and I'm having trouble using it to block a website.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "blocktwitter",
  "description": "block twitter",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
  "activeTab",
  "storage",
  "webRequest",
  "webRequestBlocking"
  ],

"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"],
"persistent": true
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) { return {cancel: true}; },
    {urls: ["https://twitter.com"]},
    ["blocking"]);
```

I copied the copy + pasted the url from twitter, and copied the code from the docs, but it's still not working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You have two problems.

### Problem #1: Invalid match pattern

The first problem is that the URL you are passing to `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener()` is not a valid [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). Match patterns require a path component. If you had looked at the [console for your background page/script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913799/google-chrome-firefox-do-not-see-extension-output-in-console/38920982#38920982) you would have seen the following error:

```
_generated_background_page.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError while running webRequestInternal.addEventListener: 'https://twitter.com' is not a valid URL pattern.
```

Your *background.js* should be something like:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        console.log('In webRequest');
        return {cancel: true};
    }, {
        urls: ["https://*.twitter.com/*"]
    }, ["blocking"]
);
```

### Problem #2: No host permission for twitter.com

You need to have permission for the host that you are blocking. You have to declare the host in your [`permissions`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) array in [*manifest.json*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest). Something like:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "blocktwitter",
  "description": "block twitter",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/*",
    "https://*.twitter.com/*",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I need your help reagarding problem...i did the same as u wrote above but website is not getting block

Comment: @twanaeng There's little or nothing that anyone can do without seeing your code. I suggest you create a new question and include enough code in the question such that readers can duplicate the problem you're having. Definitely include your *manifest.json*.

Comment: i need your suggestion  can we change the window desktop wallpaper thorugh extension ?

Comment: That's going to depend on what you mean by "window desktop wallpaper". If you mean the wallpaper that Windows uses for the desktop, the answer is: not without installing a program which is designed to both make that change and communicate with your extension, and then communicating with that program.

Comment: ok and there are some apis which says This API is only available to extensions installed by enterprise policy. What does it mean?

Comment: @twanaeng You need to be writing these up as actual questions, not asking them in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212798/discussion-between-twana-eng-and-makyen).